# What is the maximum coverage for a random sequential adsorption of discs?

Tags: random, simulation

**The answer is 0.547.**

---

I'm writing programs to simulate random sequential adsorption and find the fraction of space occupied beyond which one can't add any more objects, and I'm looking for the actual values to compare my results to. The one I can't find is the maximum surface occupied by discs dropped randomly onto a pad without touching each other (Wikipedia only has oblong 2d shapes, and the papers don't seem to put values in the abstracts). What is its theoretical value?

(I've seen the terms "jamming coverage", "saturated coverage" and "maximum coverage", and I'm not quite sure what they all mean but I think that's what I'm looking for.)

---

Details of results:

- 0.747 of length occupied by randomly placed segments on a line. (This is the [Renyi car-parking constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html) so all is good.)
- 0.449 of surface occupied by randomly placed discs on a pad. (???)
- 0.267 of volume occupied by randomly placed spheres in a box. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sequential_adsorption#Jamming_coverage_for_3d_systems) has it at 0.384 so I've got some head-scratching to do.)

---

As far as use for others goes, the Wikipedia article could be updated with the value for discs.

Comment: All disks of the same specified diameter? Of course, random hits may be far from optimal packing. If the region is the rectangle with vertices at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ and disk diameter is $1,$ then I guess optimal is four disks, one in each quadrant (covering $\pi/4 \approx .785$ of total area). But one random disk with center near $(0,0)$ already 'fills' the rectangle. That said, do you really want _randomly_ placed circles of _specified fixed_ diameter dropped onto a rectangular pad of given dimensions?

Comment: @BruceET thankyou for your reply. The surface is a 10 by 10 square, and radius is 1 for all discs. Neatly packing them side by side one could fit 25 discs (so .785 of area as you said), but I want to insert them randomly to follow the definition of a random sequential adsorption. However to my embarrasment I have just seen the value .547 is given in the lead of the Wikipedia article (I had jumped to the values section). Perhaps with a larger surface relative to the disc radius I might get closer to this result.

Comment: Thanks for interesting question. Consulting for NASA in pre-moon flight days, I considered yrs of bombardment of moon by meteors (with a hypothetical distribution of sizes and rates) necessary to 'saturate' moon's surface with craters. Answ is not very long in astro terms. Esp with sizes and rates revised (much upward) according to current knowledge. Also now that we've seen the far side of the moon, the concept of saturation tends to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.547

I am sorry for asking the question without properly searching for results.